# How to replace specific value in list?

Tags: python, list, replace

I´ve the following list:

```
x = [['0_1 1_0']]
```

I want to replace 0_1 with 0.

This is what ive already tried:

```
x[0].replace("0_1", "0")
```

But then I get the following erorr:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: `x[0]`is a list...try `x[0][0]`

Comment: but i get the error anyway

Comment: Is this the only item in the list of list? Have you only shown a part of the list? Because the above comment should not give an error for the example list you posted.

Comment: what does  `type(x[0]))` says?

Comment: Are you sure its `'0_1 1_0'` single element not a separate element. or did you simply meant, `x = [['0_1', '1_0']]`

Comment: @webDev `numpy`  lists print like that.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
x[0][0] = x[0][0].replace("0_1", "0")
```

Since:

```
>>> x = [['0_1 1_0']]
>>> x
[['0_1 1_0']]
>>> x[0]
['0_1 1_0']
>>> x[0][0]
'0_1 1_0'
>>> x[0][0] = x[0][0].replace("0_1", "0")
>>> x
[['0 1_0']]
```

And since strings are immutable, you can't change them in-place, but have to reassign to it.

Comment: I think poster's list should be something like this  x = [['0_1', '1_0']]

Comment: And how to replace it in a whole list for example: [['0 1_0'],
 ['0_2 2_0'],
 ['0_3 3_0'],
 ['0_4 4_0']

Comment: @webDev Why would you think that way when the OP has not said that it's that way? Can you read his mind better than himself? To me, it's quite clear that the element is a single string.

Comment: @Marek, that's another question. Perhaps, you should edit your question for that or ask another one.

Comment: @Marek You should make a new question for that, since that's a different task than this.

Comment: @Marek Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel like it answered this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 2D list when you do x[0] you access the list within the list. So do x[0][0].replace("0_1", "0")

Answer (score 0):

So you need to understand the eco system that where you can use replace function. For example if there is a string `I want to replace string operation properly` and you want to replace the `replace` by `learn` the that's how it works.

```
string = "I want to replace string operation properly"
new_string = string.replace("replace", "learn")
```

In your case the string item is inside of a nested list. So first you need to access to the item in the nested list:

```
test_list = [["foo_1"], ["foo_1"], ["bar_2"], ["soo_2"]]

new_list = []
for item in test_list: # iterate through the list and fix it
    print("Actual:", item[0])
    print("Replaced:", item[0].replace("foo", "who"))
    new_list.append(item[0].replace("foo", "who"))
```

Answer (score -1):

you have defined a list into a list, therefore, you need to provide both indexes to access the information that in your case is written as a block '0_1 1_0'. As a consequence, you have to change the whole block, not only the "0_1" that you want.

```
x[0][0] = '0' #--> will generate x = [['0']].
```

Another option is to define a list, element by element:

```
x = ['0_1','1_0']
```

Then, you can replace the content by providing the respective index

```
x[0] = '0'
```

I hope it works.

Best regards

Ramir